Weird Vim Python auto-indent issue
When editing Python files, I am running into a weird auto-indent issue. No matter what I do, when I open a new line, the cursor always ends up in the middle of the terminal. I expect it be aligned with either the start of the previous line or one indent over if its opening a new control block. For example:
  x = y
  |

  # or like this
  if x == y:
    |

  # pipe '|' indicates where I'd expect cursor to be because of autoindent.

However, it always like this:
  hello, world
                                    |

  or 
  if x == y:
                                    |


My terminal is 100 characters wide and it always puts the cursor at position 54 when I open a new line. Any idea why this would be happening? I've pasted my Vim settings below. This started happening recently, and it's driving me nuts. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.
  autoindent          exrc                modelines=0         smartcase           wildignore=*.pyc
  backup              filetype=python     ruler               softtabstop=2       window=0
  cmdheight=2         formatoptions=cqt   scroll=18           suffixesadd=.py     wrapmargin=5
  comments=b:#,fb:-   helplang=en         scrolloff=2         syntax=python       t_8u=
  cscopetag           hidden              secure              tabstop=2
  cscopetagorder=1    ignorecase          shiftwidth=2        textwidth=100
  cscopeverbose       incsearch           showcmd             ttymouse=sgr
  expandtab           laststatus=2        showmatch           updatetime=300
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  backupdir=~/.vim/tmp
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,!^F,o,O,e
  commentstring=# %s
  completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview
  cscopeprg=/usr/local/bin/cscope
  define=^\s*\(def\|class\)
  directory=~/.vim/tmp
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  include=^\s*\(from\|import\)
  includeexpr=substitute(substitute(substitute(v:fname,b:grandparent_match,b:grandparent_sub,''),b:p
arent_match,b:parent_sub,''),b:child_match,b:child_sub,'g')
  indentexpr=python#GetIndent(v:lnum)
  indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except
  keywordprg=python3 -m pydoc
  omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete


See if the issue persists with $ vim --clean. If yes, then you should open an issue on Vim's issue tracker. If no, then the problem is probably caused by something in your config.

After adding this autocmd FileType python setlocal indentexpr= to my vimrc, I was able to override that behavior. With that it doesn't do proper smart indenting but now I don't have the annoying issue where it puts the cursor in the middle of the screen either. Not sure what it was.
